# Is there a simpler way to detect alcohol in a blood sample using IR spectroscopy?

Tags: spectroscopy, alcohols, ir-spectroscopy

I have seen all sorts of ways to detect alcohol using NIRS (*Near InfraRed Spectrscopy*) or FTIR, but they are all quite complicated in that they are using and analyzing a very wide spectrum. In addition, it is not clear as to the environment of where the alcohol is measured in. Some presentations are talking about measuring the `OH-stretch` of the `RO-H` in the region of `3200-3650 cm^-1`.

Some related, but not very helpful questions are:

- [O-H infrared band dependence of alcohol concentration in water](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/84153/o-h-infrared-band-dependence-of-alcohol-concentration-in-water)
- These there is this [book section](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/Chapter_17%3A_Alcohols_and_Phenols/17.11_Spectroscopy_of_Alcohols_and_Phenols) which mentions various problems of published spectrum.

**Is there a cheaper and more simple way to do this detection, using *off-the-shelf* components, like IR lasers or diodes?**

---

- <sub>I suppose "cheaper" would mean to use just one or very few frequencies, so that one doesn't have to analyze an entire spectrum.</sub>
- <sub>What are these frequencies and how are they determined?</sub>

---

UPDATE:

Apparently the *Blood Alcohol Concentration* (**BAC**) is [measured differently](http://www.nutrientsreview.com/alcohol/blood-alcohol-concentration-bac.html) in different parts of the world. Just for reference:

**`0.1 g alcohol in 100 mL blood`** equals:

- `0.1%` (U.S., Canada, Australia)
- `100 mg%` (UK)
- `1 ‰ = 1 permille` grams alcohol per 1 liter blood  (EU)
- `22 mmol/L` (in hospitals) *millimols alcohol per liter blood*.

Comment: You're looking at concentrations of alcohol of approximately 0.1%. It's going to be difficult do measure that easily in an IR spectrum.

Comment: @Zhe How did you get that number?

Comment: Well, when you hit 0.5%, you're pretty close to dead if not dead, and 0.08% is the legal limit in US for driving.

Comment: The trouble with detecting alcohol (or glucose for that matter, which has been tried many times because of its utility for diabetics) in blood by IR is that blood is a very complicated mixture of things many of which also have features common to alcohol (like OH stretches). Extracting a specific signal from the noise requires vast computing power even if the signal is good enough (which is unlikely).

Comment: Interestingly, there are certain things that are significantly easier to measure. For example, a pulse oximeter reads blood O2 saturation really well, and it's just a red light that you clip to your finger.